# Yii2: how to make a <div> disabled/readonly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, yii2, disabled-input, readonly-attribute

I need to disabled or make readonly the icon of the [yii2-date-picker-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) under the Yii2 framework.

The datepicker widget has two parts: a `<span>` for the icon and a `<input>` for the date. I can disabled the `<input>` using jQuery but I can't the `<span>`.

[image: Datepicker]

This is the jQuery code:

```
$("#movements-vencimiento").prop("disabled", true); // Works.
$("#vencimientoDiv").prop("disabled", true) // Not works.
```

This is the Yii2 code:

```
<div class="col col-md-4" id="vencimientoDiv">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'vencimiento')->widget(\common\widgets\DatePicker::className(), [
        'convertFormat' => true,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'language' => 'es-AR',
            'todayHighlight' => 'true',
        ]
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

This is the HTML generated code:

```
<div id="vencimientoDiv">
    <div class="form-group field-movements-vencimiento">
        <label class="control-label" for="movements-vencimiento">Vencimiento</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="movements-vencimiento" class="form-control" name="Movements[vencimiento]" disabled="">
        </div>
        <div class="help-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A div does not have a `disabled` property. What you can do instead, is removing the event handlers that cause the calendar to show up, like this:

```
$("#vencimientoDiv *").off();
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the `pointerEvents` which works on all elements, you can disable and enable the click back whenever needed.

see a simple demo below

```js
$("#clicker").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked");
});

$("#disab").on('click', function() {
  $("#clicker").css({
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  });
})

$("#enab").on('click', function() {
  $("#clicker").css({
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#." id="clicker">click me</a>

<input type="button" value="Disable Click" id="disab">
<input type="button" value="enable Click" id="enab">
```

So in your case you will write the below to disable

```
$("#vencimientoDiv").css({pointerEvents:'none'});
```

and then enable back with

```
$("#vencimientoDiv").css({pointerEvents:'auto'});
```